# how to make <option> to <otpgroup> using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change selectbox option tag to optgroup tag using below code,

```
var oSrc = document.getElementById('SelectFeatures');

         for (var i = 0; i < oSrc.options.length; i++) {

                if (oSrc.options[i].text=="Game")
                {


                   $("#SelectFeatures option[value='Game']").wrap("<optgroup label='Game'/>"); alert("game");

                }

                else if(oSrc.options[i].text=="Lesson")
                {
                    alert("Lesson");
                   $("#SelectFeatures option[value='Lesson']").wrap("<optgroup label='Lesson'/>"); 
                }
                else if( oSrc.options[i].text=="Worksheet"){
                    alert("Worksheet");
                   $("#SelectFeatures option[value='Worksheet']").wrap("<optgroup label='Worksheet'/>");  
                }


         }
```

My jsp :

```
<select name="SelectFeatures" id="SelectFeatures" multiple="multiple"
                style="height: 315px;width:200px" onchange="Move()">

                    <option value="Lesson">Lesson</option>
                     <option value="about myself">about myself</option>
                  <option value="about yourself">about yourself</option>
                     <option value="Game">Game</option>
                    <option value="about me game">about me game</option>
                     <option value="Worksheet">Worksheet</option>
                    <option value="content" >content</option>
                <option value="content2">content2</option>
                    </select>
```

But my code not satisfying me!.Actually i want to do like below code using jquery,

```
<select name="SelectFeatures" id="SelectFeatures"  multiple="multiple"
                style="height: 315px;width:200px" onchange="Move()">                
                       <optgroup label="Lesson">
                   <option value="about myself">about myself</option>
                  <option value="about yourself">about yourself</option>
                    </optgroup>
                   <optgroup label="Game">
                    <option value="about me game">about me game</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="Worksheet">
                   <option value="content" >content</option>
                    <option value="content2" >content2</option>


     </optgroup>
```

My fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/8ybf7nke/13/

how to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add the optgroups in the jsp?

Comment: @GolezTrol so there is no solution for this???

Comment: I didn't say that. I just wondered why you are making it hard for yourself by making this modification in JavaScript.

Comment: The options are just plain elements without any attributes. So selectors like `#SelectFeatures option[value='Game']` are not going to work. There is no option with the value 'Game'.

Comment: @GolezTrol Actually i am displaying these items from DB in onload page that's what doing this one.

Comment: @GolezTrol check my question now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66318/discussion-between-manivasagam-and-goleztrol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this: Make a group, and make sure to append each next item to it. You can check the snippet below, or your [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/8ybf7nke/14/).

```js
var $options = $('#SelectFeatures option');

var $group = null; // Contains the most recently created group.

$options.each(function(){
    // Get the option and its text
    var $option = $(this);
    var text = $option.text();

    if (text === 'Lesson' || text === 'Game' || text == 'Worksheet')
    {
        // This option is a group. Create an optgroup element and replace the option with it.
        $group = $('<optgroup label="' + text + '"/>');
        $option.replaceWith($group);
    }
    else
    {
        // This is a normal option. Append it to the previously created group.
        $group.append($option);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="SelectFeatures" id="SelectFeatures" multiple="multiple"
    style="height: 315px;width:200px" onchange="Move()">
    <option>Lesson</option>
    <option>about myself</option>
    <option>about yourself</option>
    <option>Game</option>
    <option>about me game</option>
    <option>Worksheet</option>
    <option>content</option>
    <option>content2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow! You did what i expected.Thank You Mr.!